# What is the source "$HOME/somepath.ext" line in zsh or at least oh-my-zsh and why do I get 'bad assignment'?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've looked for a while and I can't seem to find why this line is even here

```
source "$HOME/some/path.ext"
```

What I am getting no matter what I try to reset it to is the following error:

```
/Users/me/.zshrc:323: bad assignment
```

Obviously the 'bad assignment' part means it's not set to what it should be but I don't understand why the line is there in the first place.

How does this work properly?

Thanks

Comment: Since you are not getting a 'no such file or directory' error, there is probably an actual file at `$HOME/some/path.ext`. What is in that file? FYI, there's a bit more info on the `source` command [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-source) and [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-_002e).

Comment: Thanks @Gairfowl. Since trying to "fix" this now I'm also not able to execute functions that were working before. facepalm

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering is why I get the bad assignment error even if I comment out that source line...

Comment: That suggests that the error is earlier in the file, possibly from a missing closing quote or parentheses. Tracking down that kind of issue sometimes takes a few trial and error iterations, and you may even need to rebuild the `.zshrc` file one step at a time. You might  also try adding `set -x` to `~/.zshrc`, although that can produce a huge amount of output.

Comment: .zshrc is a file which **you** create and maintain. Most likely you have at some time in the past used a text editor and put these lines into this files. If you now think that you don't want them, just comment them out.  As for the "bad assignment", you need to show us the line which causes this errors. After all, you know the filename and the line number. We have no supernatural abilities to peek into your file ..... If the line number is one higher than the last line of the file, you have some structure error, such as a runaway string (unclosed quote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues:

1. I forgot to put a `then` after the `elif` statements
2. I added spaces after the `=`, i.e., `alias JenniferGarner = 'Electra()'` instead of `JenniferGarner='Electra()'`
3. $HOME is simply ~/

Sometimes I forget how old and crotchety these codebases are.